# Usar from module import* vs usar import module em python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Os 2 fazem a mesma coisa(eu acho pelo menos), mas sempre me disseram que **import module** é melhor então eu sempre usei esse método, mas  o método **from module import ***  deixa o código mais conciso já que você não precisa ficar chamando o módulo toda hora. Então eu queria uma opinião mais avançada sobre isso explicando o porquê de usar um ou outro, obrigado desde já.

Comment: O minireview é uma coisa completamente a parte da sua pergunta. Em inglês existe um site separado do stackoverflow para isso - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Se você não conseguir mesmo postar em inglês acredito que tudo bem pedir o review aqui, mas faça isso numa pergunta separada, e cole o código aqui (sem links externos)

Comment: ok @jsbueno já retirei o mini-review da pergunta, desculpe

Comment: não  - tudo bem você perguntar  - eu só respondi da forma apropriada para este contexto: como comentário.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nunca use `from module import *`. 
A "concisão" nesse caso é uma ilusão.

O `*` remove um nível de determismo para o seu código, tornando impossível algumas funcionalidades de verificação de correção estática (por exemplo, se você digitar um nome de variável errado, nenhuma ferramenta vai poder apontar isso, já que não tem como saber se o nome errado existe entre o que foi importado com "*").

E isso atrapalha não só as ferramentas, como programadores humanos: em um código complexo com vários imports, depois de uma semana ou duas, você vê uma chamada a função, e não consegue saber de onde ela veio, por exemplo.

E é até perigoso: se você tem mais de uma importação com "*" no mesmo módulo, uma importação que vem depois poderia sobrepor nomes que já tinham sido importados - e você não vai ter como saber disso. Pior ainda: essa sobre-escrita da importação poderia acontecer numa versão posterior de uma biblioteca, de forma que seu código funciona quando é feito, e misteriosamente para de funcionar ao se atualizar alguma dependência.

Então: não.

Quanto a "concisão", ela é relativa. A sintaxe do `import` em Python é bem flexível, e você provavelmente tem como manter essa concisão desejada mesmo sem introduzir a ambiguidade do `*`: você pode importar só os nomes que precisa de algum módulo, por exemplo fazendo `from modulo import metodo1, metodo2`, ou, no caso de um módulo do qual você vai chamar muita coisa, usar apenas um nome menor para o mesmo, como `import numpy as np`  ou `import typing as T`.

Comment: A [PEP8 fala sobre wildcrad imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). Em que o documento está em inglês, mas a tradução pelo Google Tradutor está boa. Somente um artigo para corroborar com a resposta.